# Tensorflow Slim train Cifarnet on custom dataset

Tags: python, computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a cifarnet model on a custom dataset. I got following error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError'>, Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [6] rhs shape= [10]
     [[Node: save/Assign_8 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@CifarNet/logits/biases"], use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](CifarNet/logits/biases, save/restore_slice_8)]]
```

My reference point is https://github.com/tensorflow/models

I have created a custom dataset file (looks like slim/datasets/mnist.py), which returns number of classes as 6 but cifarnet model do not take this argument. At least this is what I understand from the error log. I am using the same dataset file for training lenet model and it works without any problem.

Is there anything wrong with cifarnet model or what might be the reason of this error?

Edit 1:

The part that I have changed is here. Rest is same with tensorflow/models repository.

Dataset:

```
slim = tf.contrib.slim

_FILE_PATTERN = '%s-00000-of-00001'

_SPLITS_TO_SIZES = {'train': 2400, 'validation': 600}

_NUM_CLASSES = 6

_ITEMS_TO_DESCRIPTIONS = {
'image': 'A [256 x 256 x 3] image.',
'label': '6 stages of brain tumor',
}

def get_split(split_name, dataset_dir, file_pattern=None, reader=None):
if split_name not in _SPLITS_TO_SIZES:
    raise ValueError('split name %s was not recognized.' % split_name)

if not file_pattern:
    file_pattern = _FILE_PATTERN
file_pattern = os.path.join(dataset_dir, file_pattern % split_name)

# Allowing None in the signature so that dataset_factory can use the default.
if reader is None:
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader

keys_to_features = {
    'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value=''),
    'image/format': tf.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string, default_value='raw'),
    'image/class/label': tf.FixedLenFeature(
        [1], tf.int64, default_value=tf.zeros([1], dtype=tf.int64)),
}

items_to_handlers = {
    'image': slim.tfexample_decoder.Image(shape=[256, 256, 3], channels=3),
    'label': slim.tfexample_decoder.Tensor('image/class/label', shape=[]),
}

decoder = slim.tfexample_decoder.TFExampleDecoder(
    keys_to_features, items_to_handlers)

labels_to_names = None
if dataset_utils.has_labels(dataset_dir):
    labels_to_names = dataset_utils.read_label_file(dataset_dir)

return slim.dataset.Dataset(
    data_sources=file_pattern,
    reader=reader,
    decoder=decoder,
    num_samples=_SPLITS_TO_SIZES[split_name],
    num_classes=_NUM_CLASSES,
    items_to_descriptions=_ITEMS_TO_DESCRIPTIONS,
    labels_to_names=labels_to_names)
```

Bash Script:

```
TRAIN_DIR=/tmp/cifar-dir/


# Where the dataset is saved to.
DATASET_DIR=/tmp/data/tfrecords/

# Run training.
bazel-bin/slim/train_image_classifier \
  --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
  --dataset_name=tissue \
  --dataset_split_name=train \
  --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} \
  --model_name=cifarnet \
  --preprocessing_name=cifarnet \
  --max_number_of_steps=10000 \
  --batch_size=32 \
  --save_interval_secs=120 \
  --save_summaries_secs=120 \
  --log_every_n_steps=100 \
  --optimizer=sgd \
  --learning_rate=0.01 \
  --learning_rate_decay_factor=0.1 \
  --num_epochs_per_decay=200 \
  --weight_decay=0.004

# Run evaluation.
bazel-bin/slim/eval_image_classifier \
  --checkpoint_path=${TRAIN_DIR} \
  --eval_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
  --dataset_name=tissue \
  --dataset_split_name=validation \
  --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} \
  --model_name=cifarnet
```

Comment: Can you point to the code you are actually executing?

Comment: Updated and added code.